# Objective C to Java: converting a typedef block

Tags: java, objective-c

I am trying to port the following typedef block:

```
typedef void (^MyBlock)(BOOL success, enumType appStatus);
```

How could I do this Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java you would use a single-method interface:

```
interface MyBlock {
    void run(boolean success, EnumType appStatus);
}
```

When you pass a new block to an API taking `MyBlock`, you do it like this:

```
someObject.runWithBlock(new MyBlock() {
    public void run(boolean success, EnumType appStatus) {
        ... // The code of your block goes here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Java have no such thing like pointer to function type.

Best analogy will be

```
intarface MyBlock {
    void perform(boolean success, enumType appStatus);
}
```

Comment: This is not true. Because there is no function type. Java 8 just have some syntactic sugar for function.

Comment: It almost makes me want to post a new question.

Comment: @RailingSam don't stop yourself :)

Comment: @talex I think I wouldn't even understand the correct answer - that would be too much of a responsibility!